# Best way to update Shopify customer level data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, shopify-api

I am looking at moving our shopify data to BigQuery for reporting purposes. I paginate through the customers endpoint from the shopify API and get all the customer level data. I then export this into a csv that I store on google cloud storage and then import to BigQuery. My question is what is the best way to deal with incremental data loads, given that some of the entries on the current customer datamart (for example, total order count) might have changed and some new customers might have been created since the last table udpate. any advice on the design pattern would be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: If you don't mind spend a bit money, there are some good SAAS tools for data integration that might just take care of the plumbing for you. Try Fivetran.

Answer (score 1):

To handle incremental data which is getting loaded on GCS (source) and target is Bigquery, you have couple of Google options:-

1. Dataflow:- You can create a Dataflow pipeline and load Incremental data to Bigquery (intermediate tables). Once data is loaded on Bigquery intermediate table, then you can calculate Current status on Joining 2 tables (target & intermediate) and get latest data appended to target Bigquery tables.
   Data calculation can be done through scheduled Dataflow pipeline or through scheduled Bigquery.
2. DataPrep:- [Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/oracle-data-to-google-bigquery-using-google-cloud-dataflow-and-dataprep-20884571a9e5) you can refer, how to create ETL Pipeline. You can add target (BigQuery table) as reference.